# Z-scoring Columns in Large Data Sets

Tags: r, dataframe, z-score

I am trying to Z-score a certain part of the data set here.

I have a table like this:
Called DF

| Participant | Date | XPL | WAYS | SPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location | TBD | 12 | 3 | 5.5 |
| George | 10_Sep_Mon | 23 | 12 | 12.7 |
| Sam | 10_Sep_Mon | 14 | 2.5 | 5 |
| Carl | 10_Sep_Mon | 21 | 2.8 | 5.1 |

I only want to apply an operation on the second row, starting on George, and just the section between XPL, WAYS and SPM. I do not want to do any calculation on the first row.

| Participant | Date | XPL | WAYS | SPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location | TBD | 12 | 3 | 5.5 |
| George | 10_Sep_Mon | **23** | **12** | **12.7** |
| Sam | 10_Sep_Mon | **14** | **2.5** | **5** |
| Carl | 10_Sep_Mon | **21** | **2.8** | **5.1** |

The end result, I want to Z-score the bolded numbers so for example, each column will be z-scored, except the first column. What is the best way to do this for a large data set with a lot of columns?

I know there is a scale() command, but is this applicable for z-scores? And if so, how can it be used here? Z-score is also the score minus the mean, all divided by standard deviation, so I am trying to see how to code this all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
Participant <- c("Location", "George", "Sam", "Carl")
Date <- c("TBD", "10_Sep_Mon", "10_Sep_Mon", "10_Sep_Mon")
XPL <- c(12, 23, 14, 21)
WAYS <- c(3, 12, 2.5, 2.8)
SPM <- c(5.5, 12.7, 5, 5.1)
DF <- data.frame(Participant, Date, XPL, WAYS, SPM)
```

Comment: `DF[-1, -(1:2)] <- scale(DF[-1, -(1:2)])`

Comment: Longer `dplyr` variation:  `bind_rows(DF[1,], slice(DF, 2:n()) %>%  mutate(across(3:5, scale)))`